# PHP DomDocument, append element of a page to another

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a php script for generate a shop.

So, first i retrieve my html page with dom document :

```
$oPage = new webHTML("boutique_panier_HTML");
$oInter = $oPage->getElementById("inter");
```

webHTML() is just a custom DomDocument class. So, i retrieve my principal div (inter) and i do some treatments into this div before `return $oPage->saveHTML();`

So, for now, it's ok.

I need to load another page, retrieve an element (form) and put this element on my `$oInter`.

So, juste before `return $oPage->saveHTML();`, i do :

```
$oPage2 = new webHTML("formulaire_bon_commande");
$oInter2 = $oPage2->getElementsByTagName("form");
$oInter->appendChild($oInter2);
```

So, i load the page "formulaire_bon_commande", i retrieve my element form, and i try to append this element to my $oInter div.

And with this code, i have just a white page... No effect. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

method `getElementsByTagName` returns `DOMNodeList`, `appendChild` expects `DOMNode`, so you have to iterate `$oInter2`

```
$oInter2 = $oPage2->getElementsByTagName("form");
foreach ($oInter2 as $el){
   $node = $oPage->importNode($el, true);
   $oInter->appendChild($node);
}
```

Example:

```
$oPage = new DOMDocument();
$oPage->loadHTML('<html><p id="inter"></p></html>');
$oInter = $oPage->getElementById("inter");


$oPage2 = new DOMDocument();
$oPage2->loadHTML('<html><form><button></button></form></html>');
$oInter2 = $oPage2->getElementsByTagName("form");
foreach($oInter2 as $el) {
    $node = $oPage->importNode($el, true);
    $oInter->appendChild($node);
}

echo $oPage->saveHTML();
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p id="inter"><form><button></button></form></p></body></html>
```